# Construction of disjoint open sets

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

> Let be $(X,\Vert\cdot\Vert)$ a normed space and $\emptyset\neq M\subset X$. We assume that there exist two subsets of $M$, denoted by $M_1,M_2$, where $M_1\cap M_2=\emptyset$. Further there exist two open sets $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ such that $Q_1\cap M=M_1$ and $Q_2\cap M=M_2$.
>
> Show that there exist two disjoint open sets $O_1$ and $O_2$, i.e. $O_1\cap O_2 = \emptyset$ such that $O_1\cap M=M_1$ and $O_2\cap M=M_2$.

**My approach:**

Let be $x\in M_1$, then there exists a $U_{\epsilon(x)}(x):=\{z\in X\mid \Vert x-z\Vert<\epsilon\}$ such that $U_{\epsilon(x)}(x)\subset Q_1$ because $Q_1$ is open. Of course $U_{\frac{\epsilon(x)}{2}}(x)\subset Q_1$. The same holds for a $y\in M_2$. So we also have a $U_{\frac{\epsilon(y)}{2}}(y)\subset Q_2$.

We define
$$
O_1:=\bigcup\limits_{x\in M_1}U_{\frac{\epsilon(x)}{2}}(x)\text{ and }O_2:=\bigcup\limits_{y\in M_2}U_{\frac{\epsilon(y)}{2}}(y).
$$
We know that $O_1$ and $O_2$ are both open and immediately see that $O_1\cap M=M_1$ and $O_2\cap M=M_2$.

If we assume that there exists a $c\in O_1\cap O_2$ then there must exist two $x,y$ with $x\in O_1$ and $y\in O_2$ such that
$$c\in U_{\frac{\epsilon(x)}{2}}(x)\subset O_1\text{ and }c\in U_{\frac{\epsilon(y)}{2}}(y)\subset O_2.$$

This implies $\Vert x-c\Vert<\frac{\epsilon(x)}{2}$ and $\Vert y-c\Vert<\frac{\epsilon(y)}{2}$ and hence $\Vert x-y\Vert \leq \Vert x-c\Vert +\Vert y-c\Vert <\frac{\epsilon(x)}{2}+\frac{\epsilon(y)}{2}$.

If $\frac{\epsilon(x)}{2}\geq\frac{\epsilon(y)}{2}$ then $\Vert x-y\Vert < \epsilon(x)\implies y\in O_1\implies y\in Q_1\implies y\in M_1$. This is a contradiction because $M_1\cap M_2=\emptyset$. If $\frac{\epsilon(x)}{2}\leq\frac{\epsilon(y)}{2}$ we also get a contradiction. Hence, $O_1\cap O_2=\emptyset$. We see that indeed $O_1$ and $O_2$ satisfy the required properties.

---

Is this correct? It seems a bit comnplicated. Maybe there is a swifter way!?